# Relationships query PostgresSQL, Follow/Unfollow functionality with PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, Users and Relationships tables. Users table has following columns:

```
id, name,password,username,email,avatar,followersCount,followingCount,tweetCount.
```

And the Relationships table has the following columns:

```
id, followingId, followerId
```

How should I go about creating a SQL query to extract a user with a specific Id and find id's from Relationships that user is following? So in other words find people that user follows

I've come this far so long

```
SELECT *
FROM public."Users" JOIN
     public."Relationships"
     ON (public."Users".id = public."Relationships".id)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Is there an issue with your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM public."Relationships" r JOIN
     public."Users" u
     ON u.id = r.followerId
WHERE r.followingId = ?;
```

`?` is a parameter placeholder for the user you care about.  This returns all the followers of that user.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this query

```
SELECT public."Users".*
FROM public."Users" 
JOIN public."Relationships"
     ON public."Users".id = public."Relationships".followingId 
     AND public."Relationships".followerId = a user ID
```

I am not really clear about `followerId` and `followingId` mean but you can change them in the query if it is not what you want.